# Learning rails. Differences between, for instance, product, :product, @product, product.id, product_id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So many variables and conventions in rails look so similar to me. If something isn't working and I suspect a particular variable is the culprit, I might change it from

```
variable
```

to

```
@variable
```

or I might change

```
product_id
```

to

```
product.id
```

I'm really just shooting in the dark, though. I don't know exactly what is used where, and I'd really like to know the key concepts.

Comment: Start by learning Ruby then Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable
```

Could be a local variable or a method in the current scope.

```
@variable
```

Is an instance variable, like any instance variables in any other class.

```
product_id
```

Is again a local variable or method in the current scope.

And the last one:

```
product.id
```

**product** could be a local variable or method and then you call the **id** method on it. You should probably invest more time trying to learn Ruby before trying to use Rails.

Comment: `product` most likely an object that has an *attribute* `id`.